# How to hook into the page wide click event?

Tags: javascript, html, click, dom-events

Just like the question states.  I want to fire off an event that calls a method everytime the user clicks on the web page.

How do I do that without use of jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without using jQuery, I think you could do it like this:

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener('click',
        function (event) {
            // handle event here
        },
        false
    );
} else if (document.attachEvent) {
    document.attachEvent('onclick',
        function (event) {
            // handle event here
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: The function receives the event as a parameter - your answer shoudl reflect that

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it..

```
if (window.addEventListener)
{    
    window.addEventListener('click', function (evt)
    {
        //do something
    }, false);
} 
else if(window.attachEvent)
{
    window.attachEvent('onclick', function (evt)
    {
        // do something (for IE)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).click(function(){});
```

Comment: and i quote: `How do I do that without use of jQuery?`

Comment: it happens to the best of us ^_^

Comment: Helps me out, when I want to know how to do it WITH jQuery! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.onclick = function() { alert("hello"); };
```

note that this will only allow for one such function though.